# Users getting logged out of my MVC3 application hosted on WinHost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I'm running ASP and MVC3 on Winhost.com and I am constantly getting logged out using Windows Forms authentication. I will go from one to two pages and it will work but when I go to our create character page it is logging you out. Sometimes it will do it, sometimes it won't and it happens randomly on different pages. I have researched but I'm having an issue finding something that matches this description.

Either that or I am just not searching the correct stuff..

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can find solution in the winhost forum:
http://forum.winhost.com/showthread.php?t=9017

Comment: @YevhenMartynov yes, that's the solution, adding the machine key

Comment: @Yevhen: =] I was going crazy with this exact behavior... Thanks for taking the time to post the question and the link. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im sure you've checked this but is it actually logging you out or maybe just hitting the logon page after being redirected from `[Authorize]` action methods with roles based access?

If you click back on your browser and go to the previous page, that also required authentication can you view it or is it bouncing you to the logon page too?

Stick a debug line in your "logout" action method and see if your ever hitting that by accident somehow?

Just some general ideas, sorry I can't help without seeing more info.

**Edit :**

Also, can you check this section in your web.config? Here's an example from one of my applications:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Logon" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

What is your timeout?

Comment: +1 Agree, if it's redirecting to login page for some pages it's probably because some have no `[Authorize]` or they have different `[Authorize]` `Users` or `Roles`

Comment: I'm not sure if it's anything to do with the Authorize. I have two [Authorize] attributes in the whole project, one of which is on ChangePassword and the other on the ChangePassword HttpPost action. Do I need to add more? I'm not entirely sure how to remedy this.

Comment: Chris, yes we are using role based access. I believe that Session.Timeout in our LogOn Action has helped. I'm not entirely sure but I do know that it is not doing it as fast as it was. It was generally happening within 10-15 seconds. Now it seems to be every couple minutes. I wish there was a way to make this work better.

Comment: Can you check your web.config? I've added an example to the question :)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a blog post regarding this exact issue in WinHost:

http://lostinthegc.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/winhost-mvc3-web-application-users-are-logged-out-sessions-lost/

It boils down to adding the necessary SQL Schema tables to support sessions and adding a Machine Key to web.config.